# How to Share compiler variables

Tags: install4j

Is it possible to declare a compiler variable in a module and then reference it it a main project that has included the module as a merged project

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As of install4j 5.1.11 this is not possible. Compiler variables are only accessible within the project where they are defined.